# 2 cluster of zookeper servers in hadoop+kafka cluster - is it posible?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have Kafka cluster with the following details

3 kafka machines

3 zookeeper servers

We also have Hadoop cluster that includes datanode machines
And all application are using the zookeeper servers, including the kafka machines

Now

We want to do the following changes

We want to add additional 3 zookeeper servers that will be in a separate cluster

And only kafka machine will use this additional zookeeper servers

**Is it possible ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the `ha.zookeeper.quorum` in Hadoop configurations to be separate from `zookeeper.connect` in Kafka configurations, such that you have two individual Zookeeper clusters, can be achieved, yes.

However, I don't think Ambari or Cloudera Manager, for example, allow you to view or configure more than one Zookeeper cluster at a time.

Comment: ha.zookeeper.quorum defined in ambari --> HDFS CONFIG --> Custom core-site  , so configure only this values is enough?

Comment: You'll probably want to copy any existing data from that Zookeeper address first

Comment: by the way how to download the zookeeper server pkgs that are relevant for hortonworks HDP - 2.6.4?

Comment: I would use the Deb or YUM repos. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.1.5/bk_ambari-installation/content/hdp_stack_repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Kafka uses Zookeeper to perform various distributed coordination tasks, such as deciding which Kafka broker is responsible for allocating partition leaders, and storing metadata on topics in the broker.

After closing kafka, the original zookeeper cluster data will be copied to the new cluster using tools, this is a zookeeper cluster data transfer util [zkcopy](https://github.com/ksprojects/zkcopy)

But if your Kafka cluster didn't stop work, you should think about Zookeeper data transfer to additional zookeeper servers.

Comment: what in case we removed all data from the kafka ( delete all topics ) and create the 3 new zookeeper servers . so in that case we start all from scratch and we not need copy data from the orig zookeeper to the new zookeeper , am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just need reconfig `zookeeper. connect` in server. properties.